# Submit a Custom Dialog Tab in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am extending vBulletin's version of CKEditor 3.6 because I want to display an additional tab inside of the image upload dialog.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev){
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'vbimage'){
        dialogDefinition.onOk = function(e){
            doSomeOtherKindOfUpload();
            return false;
        };
        dialogDefinition.addContents({
            id: 'bla',
            label: 'Additional Tab',
            /*...*/
        });
    }
});
```

This works, but how can I control the dialog's OK button? As you see I already overrode the `onOK`-method, but this of course overrides it for all page tabs. How can I define a function that is only executed when my custom page tab is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way by evaluating the DOM and the attributes elements of the dialog:

```
$('.cke_dialog_contents .cke_dialog_page_contents:visible').attr('name')
```

This works, but I don't consider it as a good solution. Isn't there a method in the CKEditor API for this?